# Map of points from non-public Google Sheets containing latitude/longitude, updated automatically

Tags: gratis, maps, spreadsheet

My Google Sheet has the latitude/longitude of my suppliers:

```
Name             Latitude     Longitude
Tube&co          44.878       32.171
Bending2000      44.894       32.140
```

The sheet has 150 rows, and is **only shared with my 4 co-workers**.

**Requirements**:

- Goal: Show a map of all suppliers
- After I change data in Google Sheets, it must be taken into account next time I open the map
- Free
- Web-based

**Bonus**:

- Besides the name, displaying more metadata columns (as a tooltip when the point is clicked) would be great. There are about 5 metadata fields that I would like to show, ideally
- Color the point based on a column of the sheet. For instance if the column has 3 different possible values, color with 3 colors.
- Great if the map is shareable with my co-worker, or even better if the map is embeddable within the spreadsheet.
- Advertisement is OK, but of course the less the better.

## What I tried

[Map-a-list](https://mapalist.com/): Refuses to work with latitude/longitude only. If I reluctantly give it the addresses too, it geocodes half of them wrong (Japan). Only two custom fields, map not embeddable in spreadsheet, every viewer of the spreadsheet has to register and perform all of the data import/setting again. Accents are lost, for instance é becomes `?`.

[Spreadsheets Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm): Does not work with spreadsheets that are not public.

[Google Maps](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/get-creative-and-make-your-own-maps-with-custom-layers-on-the-new-google-maps/):
Does not take changes into account: *"You need to re-import the spreadsheet each time you change it."*

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/spreadsheet3.html) could help, it is a sheet that creates a set of placemarks in Maps. I have never tried it so I'm not sure it meets your requirements, but looks promising.